# 'Fake' variants in expl3

Tags: expansion, expl3

Suppose you have a function that operates on three tokens,

```
\cs_new:Nn \@@_on_three:NNN { #1, #2, #3 }
```

And you have a variable whose value is the three tokens:

```
\tl_set:Nn \l@@_three_tl { foo }
```

And you would like to have a variant

```
\@@_on_three:V
```

so that you can say

```
\@@_on_three:V \l@@_three_tl
```

However, if I'm not mistaken, a direct `\cs_generate_variant` would be confused by the different number of arguments (`NNN` vs. `V` or `x`), and in any case it will pass the expanded argument *within braces*, right?

So what you need is a kind of 'fake' variant, defined as:

```
\cs_new:Nn \@@_on_three:V
  { \exp_last_unbraced:Nx \@@_on_three:NNN #1 }
```

To be clear: **this works**. My question is rather whether there was another way to do this that is less 'naughty'---less mid-level tricking of `expl3`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The definition

```
\cs_new:Nn \@@_on_three:V
  { \exp_last_unbraced:Nx \@@_on_three:NNN #1 }
```

is by the guidelines of `expl3` programming 'wrong'. A `V`-type variant should be related to an `n`-type underlying function, and should not make assumptions about the content of the variable being processes. For example, what happens with

```
\tl_set:Nn \l_@@_three_tl { A }
```

with the definition of `\@@_on_three:V` given? Also, you are `x`-type expanding rather than `V`-type expanding, which will fail for example if the variable passed is a TeX register or if it contains something like LaTeX2e 'protected' code.

To be clear: it's not required that you use `\cs_generate_variant:Nn` to create variants, but it is 'required' that they behave in the same way as if they were. There are various hand-tuned variants in for example `l3tl`, but this is only to improve performance and does not alter behaviour. See also the fact that we've recently tightened up a lot of `x`-type variants as they did not show the correct outcomes in this regard.

The question does not say, but it reads as if the `tl` here is being using to store some structured data which will always consist of three tokens. As such, what seems to be wanted is

```
\cs_new:Nn \@@_on_three:N
  { \exp_last_unbraced:No \@@_on_three:NNN #1 }
```

where the semantics are that `\@@_on_three:N` should be used with a `tl` containing exactly three tokens. This is common is low-level work, and similar code is used for example in parts of the experimental output routine (`xor`) (which I'm supposed to be revising).

Comment: Thanks, Joseph. You're right about everything (yes, the tl *is* internal data, the program *should* choke if the variable is not 3 tokens, and the confusion between V and x *is* there). And your answer is exactly what I needed, just reassurance that the procedure is common (although I will adopt the :N instead of the :V as you suggest)

Comment: @Federico: depending on whether the data comes from a "trusted" source or not, you may want to add a test that the argument really is three tokens, so `\cs_new:Nn \@@_on_three:N { \int_compare:nNnTF { \tl_count:N #1 } = \c_three { \exp_last_unbraced:No \@@_on_three:NNN } { \msg_error:nnx { mypkg } { mymsg } { \tl_to_str:N #1 } } }`